# Default Constructor is getting executed before Static block in java

Tags: java, constructor, static-initializer

When we load a class in java, first **static block** get executed and then **default constructor**. but in below peace of code, What I observed that **default constructor** is getting executed before static block.

```
    public class Hello {

    private static Hello hello = new Hello();

    public Hello() {
        System.out.println("Hello Default Constructor");
    }

    static {
        System.out.println("Hello Static Block");
    }

    public static Hello createHelloInstance() {
        return hello;
    }
}
```

Main Class:

```
   public class MainTest {

        public static void main(String a[])
        {
            Hello.createHelloInstance();
        }
    }
```

Output:

```
Hello Default Constructor
Hello Static Block
```

I need to know the fundamental concept behind that. what is that so happening. ?
Could someone help me to understand the flow behind that.

Comment: The default constructor is being invoked in a static field initializer. That gets called before the static block.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a static member (`hello`) which is initialized with a `new Hello()` call that calls the default constructor. Since this member is declared before the `static` block, it will be initialized first. If you move it after the block, the block will be executed first:

```java
public class Hello {
    static {
        System.out.println("Hello Static Block");
    }
    private static Hello hello = new Hello();

    // etc...
}
```

Or better yet, make the order explicit by moving the initialization inside the block.

```java
public class Hello {
    private static Hello hello;
    static {
        System.out.println("Hello Static Block");
        hello = new Hello();
    }

    // etc...
}
```

Answer (score 3):

IN the same way instance field initialiser expressions are inserted into constructors, static field initialiser expressions are inserted into the static initialiser in order of appearance.

So

```
private static Hello hello = new Hello();

...

static {
    System.out.println("Hello Static Block");
}
```

Is the equivalent of:

```
private static Hello hello;

...

static {
    hello = new Hello();
    System.out.println("Hello Static Block");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, but you have this line of code:

```
private static Hello hello = new Hello();
```

and that is reason why you have constructor executed first. Static initializers are executed before constructor.